# Weird jQuery Mobile highlight behavior on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a pretty average jQuery Mobile app. On the bottom there is a navbar with icons and text.

This is how it should look

[image: Normal]

but when I tap/click on the page it toggles to this

[image: Abnormal]

To save myself some repetition, I've been appending the same footer to each page using this basic script.

```
$(function ()
{
    $("div[data-role='page']").append($("#footer").html());
    $("body").trigger('create');
});
```

And here's the HTML.

```
   <div class="hidden" id="footer">
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
            <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#maps" data-transition="none" data-page="maps" data-icon="grid">Maps</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#rules" data-transition="none" data-icon="bullets">Rules</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#schedule" data-transition="none" data-icon="calendar">Schedule</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#settings" data-transition="none" data-page="settings" data-icon="gear">Settings</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I believe this script is the cause of this issue. Any ideas for how to fix this behavior?

EDIT: In inspecting the DOM I found that a class called "ui-fixed-hidden" is being toggled on the data-role="footer" div when I click.

Comment: Seems like you have multiple divs with the same ID's.

Comment: Nope, they're unique. The script appends the html of the #footer div.

Comment: Right, my mistake.
To create the footer, could you try `$("div[data-role='page']").trigger('create');` ?

Comment: Or `$('[data-role="footer"]').trigger('create');` would be more precise.

Comment: add `data-tap-toggle="false"` to footer div. use `.toolbar()` to create a footer/header not `.trigger("create")`.

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more code?, it's really hard to spot the error without much code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that just because my template footer div was nested in another div with "display: none" doesn't mean that jQuery Mobile wasn't using that element. As such, I had multiple footers which created weird behaviors.

I resolved this by moving my template footer to a seperate html file and then loading it in on page start.